# Need a regular expression to capture all input functions in a python file

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to capture/get number of input functions used in a python code.

I tried this:
/input\((.)*\)/gm

But I don't want it to capture something like this:

```
someVariable = "input( )"
```

The regex I want should be able to do something like this:

Code:

```py
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
someVariable = "input( )"
number2 = int(input ("Number: ") )
```

The output should be 2 matches (input function in line 1 and 3).
It should not match the **input()** in line 2.

P.S: I am new to regex, so it would be nice if you could also write an explanation for your regex solution.

Comment: What have tried so far? I don't see the regex (`/input((.)*)/gm`) you are talking about in your code.

Comment: How *"The output should be 2"*? What do you mean by *"It should not count.."*?

Comment: That code is just an example.
I need to run the regex on the python code (As a string).

Comment: regexr.com/4o2ms Check this out for clarification.

Comment: Re: "What do you mean by "It should not count.."?" 

I mean the regex should not match the input( ) in "input ( )" since its not a function, just a string  (LINE 2)

Comment: Don't use regex to [parse structured data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7553525), that's not what regex is for. What you need is a structure-aware parser for the structured data you're trying to parse, like the standard library modules [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html) and [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using regular expressions to solve this problem for roughly the same reasons that [you should not use regular expressions to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2301287). Whatever regular expression that you come up with will likely [not capture 100% of cases](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) anyway and will end up being overly complex and unmaintainable.

A much more reliable way of counting the number of calls to a particular function in Python is to convert the Python file into an **abstract syntax tree** via Python's built-in [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module. From there you should be able to traverse the AST to extract your answer.

**Example**

Given the target Python file (`test.py`):

```py
a = input("Hello: ")
b = "input()"
c = input("World: ")
```

In a separate Python file:

```py
import ast
file = open('test.py', 'r')
tree = ast.parse(file.read())

function1 = tree.body[0].value.func  # the function that was called on line 1
print(function1.id == "input")  # true
```